# Logs are not showing in Airflow UI 2.7.2

Tags: docker, logging, docker-compose, airflow

The logs in my airflow setup are not showing - but the interesting part here is that for one my dags it does show the logs as expected. But all my other dags it doesn't and I can't figure out whats wrong.

I'm running airlfow 2.7.2 in a docker environment on my machine with python3.9, using CeleryExecutor

Here's what my airflow.cfg looks like:

```
[core]
executor = CeleryExecutor
sql_alchemy_conn = postgresql+psycopg2://airflow:airflow@postgres/airflow
dags_are_paused_at_creation = true
load_examples = false
load_default_connections = false
fernet_key = 

[database]
sql_alchemy_conn = postgresql+psycopg2://airflow:airflow@postgres/airflow

[celery]
result_backend = db+postgresql://airflow:airflow@postgres/airflow
broker_url = redis://:@redis:6379/0

[smtp]
smtp_host = SMTP_HOST
smtp_port = SMTP_PORT
smtp_user = SMTP_USER
smtp_password = SMTP_PASSWORD 
smtp_mail_from = SMTP_MAIL_FROM

[logging]
base_log_folder = /opt/airflow/logs
logging_level = INFO
# logging_config_class = log_config.LOGGING_CONFIG

[scheduler]
enable_health_check = true

[webserver]
base_url = http://localhost:8080
auth_backend = airflow.api.auth.backend.deny_all
authenticate = false
rbac = false
```

Here is my docker-compose:

```
version: '3.8'
x-airflow-common:
  &airflow-common
  build: .
  environment:
    _PIP_ADDITIONAL_REQUIREMENTS: ${_PIP_ADDITIONAL_REQUIREMENTS:-}
  volumes:
    - ${AIRFLOW_PROJ_DIR:-.}/dags:/opt/airflow/dags
    - ${AIRFLOW_PROJ_DIR:-.}/logs:/opt/airflow/logs
    - ${AIRFLOW_PROJ_DIR:-.}/config:/opt/airflow/config
    - ${AIRFLOW_PROJ_DIR:-.}/plugins:/opt/airflow/plugins
    - ./airflow.cfg:/opt/airflow/airflow.cfg
  user: "${AIRFLOW_UID:-50000}:0"
  depends_on:
    redis:
      condition: service_healthy
    postgres:
      condition: service_healthy

services:
  postgres:
    image: postgres:13
    environment:
      POSTGRES_USER: airflow
      POSTGRES_PASSWORD: airflow
      POSTGRES_DB: airflow
    volumes:
      - postgres-db-volume:/var/lib/postgresql/data
    healthcheck:
      test: ["CMD", "pg_isready", "-U", "airflow"]
      interval: 10s
      retries: 5
      start_period: 5s
    restart: always

  redis:
    image: redis:latest
    expose:
      - 6379
    healthcheck:
      test: ["CMD", "redis-cli", "ping"]
      interval: 10s
      timeout: 30s
      retries: 50
      start_period: 30s
    restart: always

  airflow-webserver:
    <<: *airflow-common
    command: webserver
    ports:
      - "8080:8080"
    healthcheck:
      test: ["CMD", "curl", "--fail", "http://localhost:8080/health"]
      interval: 30s
      timeout: 10s
      retries: 5
      start_period: 30s
    restart: always
    depends_on:
      <<: *airflow-common-depends-on
      airflow-init:
        condition: service_completed_successfully
    env_file:
      - .env

  airflow-scheduler:
    <<: *airflow-common
    command: scheduler
    healthcheck:
      test: ["CMD", "curl", "--fail", "http://localhost:8974/health"]
      interval: 30s
      timeout: 10s
      retries: 5
      start_period: 30s
    restart: always
    depends_on:
      <<: *airflow-common-depends-on
      airflow-init:
        condition: service_completed_successfully
    env_file:
      - .env

  airflow-worker:
    <<: *airflow-common
    command: celery worker
    healthcheck:
      test:
        - "CMD-SHELL"
        - 'celery --app airflow.providers.celery.executors.celery_executor.app inspect ping -d "celery@$${HOSTNAME}" || celery --app airflow.executors.celery_executor.app inspect ping -d "celery@$${HOSTNAME}"'
      interval: 30s
      timeout: 10s
      retries: 5
      start_period: 30s
    environment:
      <<: *airflow-common-env
      DUMB_INIT_SETSID: "0"
    restart: always
    depends_on:
      <<: *airflow-common-depends-on
      airflow-init:
        condition: service_completed_successfully

  airflow-triggerer:
    <<: *airflow-common
    command: triggerer
    healthcheck:
      test: ["CMD-SHELL", 'airflow jobs check --job-type TriggererJob --hostname "$${HOSTNAME}"']
      interval: 30s
      timeout: 10s
      retries: 5
      start_period: 30s
    restart: always
    depends_on:
      <<: *airflow-common-depends-on
      airflow-init:
        condition: service_completed_successfully

  airflow-init:
    << : *airflow-common
    container_name: airflow_init
    entrypoint: /bin/bash
    command:
      - -c
      - |
        airflow db init &&
        airflow users create
          --role Admin
          --username airflow
          --password airflow
          --email airflow@airflow.com
          --firstname airflow
          --lastname airflow 
    restart: on-failure
```

I saw this as well on github: https://github.com/apache/airflow/issues/31059

It might be a known issue with 2.7.2 but then why do the logs show up for my one dag?

[image: Screenshot of what my logs show]